# is it a bad idea to load into memory 160000 variables in a php script?

Tags: php

im processing a large file with sentences, i only care about the lines that have english or japanese, so while im reading the file, if i find english or japanese sentence, i want to just save it in an array and after finished reading, open another file for writting and output all the sentences in the array. this would result in me setting about 160,000 variables. all strings, some short some long. just wondering if its a bad idea to for memeory to set so many values?

example line from the file:
"1978033    jpn 彼女は口は悪いですけど根は優しい人ですよ。"

Comment: You wouldn't have 160k variables. You'd have one array (which is the variable), with 160k values in the arrray.

Comment: yes i meant an array of 160K values, it would be one array. and i wanted to know if that would be a bad idea for memory.

Comment: Why not write the lines to the file directly?

Comment: sorry, my mistake was not knowing i could have more than one file handle and have one file open for writing and the other open for reading. And so yes, i wrote directly to the other file rather than saving in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on your program construct and available system memory.

Why don't you give it a try to find out how your program behaves? Do some kind of benchmark and figure what number of lines makes best use of the available memory and at the same time give the optimum performance.